# Normal operators on a hilbert space over the reals - does $norm(Tx)=norm(T^*x)$ imply $T$ normal?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The title states the question. It's easy to prove the result for scalars C via polarisation identities but I don't think the same method works in the real case:

Let $S=TT^*-T^*T$ then one obtains $<x,Sx>=0$ for all $x$ in the space and the complex polar identities can be used to get $S=0$. However this line of reasoning fails in the real case. For example if $S$ were a 2 by 2 matrix with 0's in the diagonals and -1 and 1 in the other corners. Any suggestions? Every book I come across seems to only deal with the complex case.

Is the result even true in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The result is indeed true.

We have $S = TT^* - T^*T$.  As you said, we may conclude that $\langle x, Sx \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in X$, which in this case is a real vector space.

We may use this information conclude that $S$ is skew-adjoint, that is, $S^* = -S$.

We then additionally note that
$$
S^* = (TT^*)^* - (T^*T)^* = TT^* - T^*T = S
$$
So that $S$ is also self-adjoint.

Because $S^* = S$ and $S^* = -S$, we may conclude that $S = -S$ so that $S = 0$.

---

**Proving that $S$ is skew-adjoint:**

Note that $\langle x, Sx \rangle = 0$, and we may also state
$$
\langle x+y, S(x+y) \rangle = 0 \quad \forall x,y \in X \implies\\
\langle x, Sx \rangle + \langle x,Sy \rangle
+ \langle y,Sx \rangle + \langle y,Sy \rangle = 0  \quad \forall x,y \in X \implies\\
\langle x,Sy \rangle+ \langle y,Sx \rangle = 0 \quad \forall x,y \in X  \implies\\
\langle Sx,y \rangle = -\langle S^*x,y \rangle  \quad \forall x,y \in X  \implies\\
S = -S^*
$$